# How to make a html embedded inside iframe responsive?

Tags: html, iframe, responsive-design, jasperserver

The HTML page is from a link, and the link is not responsive i.e. the HTML page is not responsive. And I have embedded it in an iframe, so how to make it responsive?

```
<div class="video-container">
<iframe src="http://localhost:8082/jasperserver-pro/"somereport.html" 
width="400" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container iframe,  
.video-container object,  
.video-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can say You can't do that.

You can not apply CSS to HTML that is loaded in an iframe in your website so you can't make it responsive